# Java convert string to date issue

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

i have a simple method to convert dates

```
private static SimpleDateFormat uiSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a");

try {
        
        System.out.println("DATE1 " + date);
        String abc1 = uiSDF.format(date);
        System.out.println("DATE2 " + abc1);
        Date abc2 = uiSDF.parse(abc1);
        System.out.println("DATE3 " + abc2);
        return uiSDF.parse(uiSDF.format(date));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println(DateConverter.class.getName() + " convertDBTimeStampToUIDate :" + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

convert the date to a string with a new format and convert that string into a date.  issue is the .parse returns back the format to its original.

```
DATE1 Fri Oct 09 21:11:40 SGT 2020   
DATE2 Oct 09, 2020 09:11 PM
DATE3 Fri Oct 09 21:11:00 SGT 2020
```

DATE3 sysout should be same as DATE2 since i used the same uiSDF simpledateformat.  Any idea why is reverting back to original date format?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: You are not parsing the second's part in the format, you should use format like `MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a`

Comment: You're not changing the time zone's in anyway and `Date#toString` will make use of the systems timezone information to represent the date - `Date` DOES NOT carry ANY concept of formatting, nor can you (realistically) change the how the `toString` method treats it.  This is WHY there is a `DateTimeFormatter` class, to seperate the concept of "time" from the concept of "output"